# Calculate "age" MongoDB document DateTimeField Flask

Tags: python, mongodb, flask

I'm using python 3.4 and flask 0.10 with MongoDB 2.6 standard for my application. With mongo Document. I want to calculate the "age" or "years" from Persons just with its Birthday. I have this code:

```
import datetime
from Personal import db

class Person(db.Document):
    ID = db.StringField(required=True, primary_key=True, unique=True, max_length=6)
    name = db.StringField(required=True)
    birthday = db.DateTimeField(required=True)
    age = ########
```

I tried with

```
age = int(datetime.datetime.now.year) - int(birthday).year
```

And I know it's wrong. I already read the Mongo Documents guide, didn't help:

http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/defining-documents.html

Please, Indeed help with DateTime operations

Thanks

Comment: are you using mongo engine?

Comment: Yes, I'm using mongoengine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feature you're looking for could be in python instead of mongodb, using a `property` you can achieve that quite easily:

```
class Person(db.Document):
    ID = db.StringField(required=True, primary_key=True, unique=True, max_length=6)
    name = db.StringField(required=True)
    birthday = db.DateTimeField(required=True)

    @property
    def age(self):
        return ((datetime.datetime.now() - self.birthday).days) / 365
```

with that class, you're allowed to do this:

```
>>> p = Person(name='rafael', birthday=datetime.datetime(year=1990, day=1, month=1))
>>> p.age
24
```

But you won't be able to query by age, since it's not kept on your database.

Comment: Thanks, really help me :) . Now I have to think the way to store it on my database.

Comment: @YecidYahuita why store? I believe you could query on the birthday if you wanted to get people who are a certain age. You will, of course, have to craft a query specifically for that with $gte / $lte, but is possible.

Comment: Might you provide me a link with documentation of $gte / $lte  please. Thanks